# Portrait of Stephen Butterworth

Tags: biographical-details, physicists

Does anybody know of a portrait of British physicist [Stephen Butterworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Butterworth) (1885-1958)?

Comment: Did you check his obituary in Times?

Comment: You'll have to .... **filter** your search criteria

Comment: My pleasure: https://networthroll.com/stephen-butterworth-net-worth/ . I found it by searching for `"stephen butterworth" physicist` on the https://images.google.com .

Comment: I'm also interested in obtaining a portrait of Stephen Butterworth (1885--1958), the British physicist. Are there any family members (user13378?) who could help publicise one? A good start would be to add a verified portrait to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Butterworth It's a shame that there isn't a verified portrait available and, as a consequence, portraits of C. F. Powell are mislabelled as S. Butterworth on the web. (The above slide shows C. F. Powell.)

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Apparently, Prof. Silage made a mistake and used a wrong picture for his book. So, the mystery remains. The obituary in "Times," if someone can access it, might contain a picture.

---

Old answer:

Here is a picture. The page is taken from [Chapter 2, "Frequency Domain Analysis"](https://astro.temple.edu/%7Esilage/Chapter2MS.pdf) in Dennis Silage, "Analog and Digital Communications." Where did Silage find the photograph I do not know, you can email him and ask.

[image]

Comment: This picture is not Stephen Butterworth (inventor of the Butterworth filter) to whom the text refers. Stephen Butterworth was my grandfather and this is definitely not him!

Comment: The image is *not* Stephen B, but [C. F. Powell - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=C.+F.+Powell&sxsrf=AOaemvJ_AyGozMFmP0y2X0T5Kh51-ZpSpQ:1632318352786&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiuuc_c25LzAhWomeAKHS2TDVYQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1530&bih=1638&dpr=1.25).  (And no, I'm not aware of being related except in name.)